# Convert recipient address to Internet email address

Tags: lotus-domino

Currently we are experiencing some problems with VPN connection and unable to access other Domino Server. Somehow the internet connection is OK, so we can send the email if we are using user's Internet address.

Currently there are hundreds of email stuck in our Mail.Box, that I need to convert the recipients into their Internet address.

Is there any faster and efficient way to convert them instead of edit the emails and change the address one by one ?

Kindly advise

Comment: You could write an agent to process the all the documents in Mail.box, but it's really not advisable.Testing could only be done with live messages, and if you get things wrong you might end up delivering messages to the wrong recipients.

Comment: actually i have done it using Lotus Script agent, but as you said, when the agents goes wrong, it will mess the live message.If there is any administrator tool will be great